# Excel VBA: Editing existing conditional formatting rules for new rows

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I've got a spreadsheet with some conditional formatting applied to certain ranges of cells (eg. `$B$4:$F$5`). I set up a macro to add a new row, copying the formatting + formulas in the current last row. Problem is, each time I add a new row an additional conditional formatting rule is created affecting only the new row.

How do I use VBA to extend the conditional I've already set up - making the rule affect `$B$4:$F$6`?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried? Yes/No and "Please give me code that does XYZ" questions don't do pretty well on this site. Did you read [ask]?

Comment: What version of excel are you running? The bug about potential thousands of near identical CFRs from copying was fixed in Excel 2010 and (I believe) fixed in a service pack for xl2007. And **no** you cannot adjust the applied range without destroying the original and recreating it.

Comment: @Jeeped "destroying the original and recreating it" -> therefore possible... at least if you only consider the result and not the means to get there ;-)

Comment: @Jeeped using 365. edit: so i guess 2016

Comment: @Mat'sMug apologies - i've not tried anything special vba-wise as i'm brand new to this, so it's all a bit difficult to understand. tried recording editing the range but wasn't picking anything up

Comment: Fill down and delete the constants instead of copying and paste special, values and formats. That should unequivocally extend the CFR to the new row.

Comment: @Jeeped you nailed it. works perfectly, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill down and delete the constants instead of copying and paste special, values and formats. That should unequivocally extend the CFR to the new row.

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    With .Range(.Cells(4, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
        .Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, 0).Resize(2, .Columns.Count).FillDown
        On Error Resume Next
        'Debug.Print .Offset(.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Address(0, 0)
        .Offset(.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(1, .Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End With
```